# how to implement http requests in a text editor just like sql

Tags: http, http-headers

I want to know is there any way in which I can write http requests on my own just like I write sql queries for accessing a database. I mean I will type my own http request query in a text editor and it will provide me with the desired web resource. Is there any way for it??

Comment: what does a text editor have to do with http? You can easily type your own http requests, but a text editor won't help with anything except the actual typing of the request.

Comment: Ya I want to know how and where to execute http request queries

Comment: telnet to port 80 of whatever server you want to test it on, type in the http requests.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for a tool like Curl or Insomnia?

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ IDEA has this functionality in `.http` files.

[image: IntelliJ IDEA http scratch]

There is also a similar plugin to Visual Studio Code: https://github.com/Huachao/vscode-restclient

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Huachao/vscode-restclient#readme

You can use this tool to try this out.

Also, did you try using cURL in Terminal or PowerShell. Something like this:

```
curl --request GET --url 'https://my.api.mockaroo.com/data.json?key=12345' --header 'content-type: : application/json' --header 'user-agent: vscode-restclient'
```